# ASP.NET - What's the best practice for reading localized strings from XML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, localization

I got an assignment to localize the website and to store all string values into the XML file.
The reason for that is to let the sys. admin to change the localized values himself by editing XML file.

Should I read the content of XML file and store in the memory on application startup? I guess there's a best practice for this kind of scenario.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A best practice would be to use ASP.NET provided infra-structure for localization/globalization (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx). For localization, it essentially uses implicit/explicit syntax in web pages - for example,

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="XY" meta:resourcekey="Button1" /> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1Caption %>" />
```

Now, you want to use a custom xml file - so all you have to do is to provide code that will look for resource values from your xml file. This is possible by writing your [custom resource provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceproviderfactory.aspx).

See [this](http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/03/aspnet-20-custom-resource-provider.html) article that explains building resource provider to read localized strings from sql database - you can use the example to build provider for reading from your xml file.

Comment: Do I need to recompile the web application every time when I change the string value within XML file?

Comment: Not really - strictly speaking, it depends on what code you write in resource provider but then the most probable code here would be to open xml file and read the needed data from it (from performance perspective, you may cache the xml contents etc) - so you don't need a recompile. In case of .NET resource (resx) files, those get embedded within assembly hence the need for recompile. Again, note that strings for other languages would get packaged in different assembly and won't need recompile of original app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your teacher or project calls for this, but the accepted practice for globalizing/localizing .NET application is to use string resources, and use resource assemblies with satellite assemblies:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x.aspx

Comment: It's the project requirement. I'm not allowed to use the resource files.